# React multiples useState in one Context

Tags: reactjs, components

I need improve the performance in this code.

When I updated a state for example the scenario all other states are updated because the context component change.

I need that if a state changes, only the components that are waiting for that state are updated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't bailout render with Context API.

Here is a simple example demonstrating it:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// People wonder why the component gets render although the used value didn't change
const Context = React.createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    const count = () => setCounter(p => p + 1);
    return [counter, count];
  }, [counter]);
  return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

const Consumer = React.memo(() => {
  useContext(Context);
  console.log("rendered");
  return <>Consumer</>;
});

const ContextChanger = () => {
  const [, count] = useContext(Context);
  return <button onClick={count}>Count</button>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Consumer />
      <ContextChanger />
    </Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image: Edit Context API Problem]

So possible solutions are:

- Use a `Context.Provider` for **each** value.
- Use state management library like Recoil.js, Redux, Mobx.